# git clone fails for Heroku project

Tags: git, ssh, heroku, public-key

(on Mac)
I'm trying to clone my project from my new computer. I first generated the ssh key pairs:

```
heroku keys:add /Users/y/.ssh/heroku_rsa.pub
```

`heroku keys` shows:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC...B9DjpXg3fb y@server.local
```

When I try to clone my project by `git clone git@heroku.com:xyz.git`

```
Cloning into xyz...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '50.19.85.132' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

This is strange.

EDIT: If I don't rename my pub key file then it works. Somehow heroku doesn't like renaming my keys.. in other words, use the deault `id_rsa.pub` name.

Comment: Do you have `%HOME%` defined to `C:/Users/y`? (do you have `%HOME%` defined at all?)

Comment: did you add the private key to your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (or wherever your SSH server looks for it). It not, the SSH server won't know what to do w/ a private key authentication.

Comment: I don't have a authorized_keys file. I never had do write to such a file on my previous machine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like your key is not loaded. Only default named key (id_rsa) loaded by default. Load the heroku key by using ssh-add command:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/heroku_rsa
```

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar problem.  At first, I did not have a key called id_rsa.pub.  I only had a key for github: github_rsa.pub.  I ran `heroku keys` and saw that it did recognize that I had a key.  But apparently heroku does not like that github key.  Here's what I did:

```
$ssh-keygen -t rsa
$heroku keys:clear
$heroku keys:add 
$git clone git@heroku.com:my-app.git -o heroku
```

This downloaded all the files for the project successfully.

Comment: and guess what ... it keeps telling me after this .. 
Cloning into 'strong-spring-610-218'...

 !  No such app as strong-spring-610-218.

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: if you already have keys, you don't have to do: $ssh-keygen -t rsa so skip that step; start with $heroku keys:clear; then  $heroku keys:add and it will prompt with a list of your keys to add; don't select the github one - in my case I chose: id_rsa.pub; then ran that last line to clone my app - all good thanks gstroup!

Comment: so awesome, heroku keys:clear then keys:add was just what i needed, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
heroku git:clone -a "your_project_name_on_heroku"
```

This simple command  works fine (provided that your ssh key is correctly added before)