# How come Heroku is giving a permission denied error?

Tags: macos, git, heroku

When

```
$ git clone -v git@heroku.com:testabcde.git Cloning into testabcde...
```

Heroku returns

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

When

```
$ heroku keys
```

returns

```
=== 1 key for ohho@gmail.com
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC...lXLyj9YQ== ohho@gmail.com
```

now

```
$ ssh -v git@heroku.com -T

OpenSSH_5.2p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to heroku.com [50.19.85.154] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/ohho/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/ohho/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/ohho/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5pgsql1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5pgsql1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.2
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'heroku.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/ohho/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/ohho/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/ohho/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Remote: Forced command: /home/git/bin/git_proxy ohho@gmail.com
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug1: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
debug1: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
debug1: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
debug1: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
debug1: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
debug1: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
debug1: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/ohho/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

How to fix the `Permission denied (publickey)` error?

UPDATE (file permission info):

```
drwxr-xr-x  11 ohho    staff    374 Sep 16 09:37 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 50 ohho    staff   1700 Sep 15 10:34 ..
-rw-------   1 ohho    staff   1743 Sep 16 09:37 github_rsa
-rw-r--r--   1 ohho    staff    390 Sep 16 09:37 github_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--   1 ohho    staff    390 Sep  9 09:47 github_rsa.pub_bak-github
-rw-------   1 ohho    staff   1743 Sep  9 09:47 github_rsa_bak-github
-rw-------   1 ohho    staff    736 Dec  2  2010 id_dsa
-rw-r--r--   1 ohho    staff    606 Dec  2  2010 id_dsa.pub
-rw-------   1 ohho    staff   1743 Jan 28  2011 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--   1 ohho    staff    399 Jan 28  2011 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--@  1 ohho    staff  10752 Sep 16 11:47 known_hosts
```

Comment: Can you `chmod 700` the `.ssh`? (right now it is at `755`)

Comment: after `chmod 700` gives same errors

Comment: Then you can try the `ssh.exe` workaround.

Comment: that might have been interesting to know from the start ;) And what version of Git are you using?

Comment: Fixed by: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305673/git-clone-fails-for-heroku-project

Comment: I have included it in my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With msysgit, check the permissions on your `.ssh` directory from a bash session (they should be `700`), and the files in it (`600`).
Check out the [issue 261](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=261) and see if one of the workaround works, like (if everything else fails) replacing the `ssh.exe` by one from cygwin.

The OP [ohho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88597/ohho) mentions the SO question "[git clone fails for Heroku project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305673/git-clone-fails-for-heroku-project/7314578#7314578)", which recommends to load the heroku key (when it has a different name than the default `id_rsa`):

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/heroku_rsa
```

That is a solution especially if you have already an `id_rsa` private key (for other purposes than heroku)

Comment: File permissions info added in UPDATE section.

Comment: @ohho: did you try to group every connection parameter in a config file? As in http://stackoverflow.com/q/2811387

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue and could solve doing:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

(private key for the public key added to heroku)

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue on this. 
I had an app, then create another app, same account. First app still works with git but can't do anything with git in second app even other actions (such as logs... ) still work!

This works for me: 
- clear heroku current keys:

```
heroku keys:clear
```

- Delete your current private keys at **~/.ssh/** or windows **C:\Users\.ssh**
- Create new key pair:

  ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your.email@domain.com"
- Upload to heroku:

  heroku keys:add

It will list current key pairs you have and ask for the one you want to upload, enter number

Done.