# Heroku Public Key Permission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've been trying to set up my Rails project on Heroku from Ubuntu (I was using Windows, but decided to change). I'm having trouble with the public key. At first I just copied my key from windows and `heroku add:keys` it. It didn't work and I kept getting `Permission Denied (Public Key)` when I tried to clone. I also tried to generate new keys, remove old keys and add new ones, I've tried pretty much every solution I could find here on StackOverflow and Google:

[Permission denied (publickey) when deploying heroku code. fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269922/permission-denied-publickey-when-deploying-heroku-code-fatal-the-remote-end)

http://www.rorexperts.com/git-push-heroku-master-permission-denied-publickey-t2280.html

[How come Heroku is giving a permission denied error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440273/heroku-permission-denied-publickey)

http://zylstra.wordpress.com/2008/08/29/overcome-herokus-permission-denied-publickey-problem/

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/208308

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/heroku/SgiGDafu4Gg

http://eveningsamurai.wordpress.com/2011/07/13/herokus-permission-deniedpublickey-problem/

None of these helped... is there anything else that could be wrong? Is there any other information I can give to make it easier to spot the problem?

Comment: Did you get this working? If so, how? I have the same issue

Comment: I didn't, but I left the company I was working (and having this issue) and I stopped trying

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setup a different ssh key for your ubuntu installation. You first need to install the `heroku gem`, but it sounds like you have that done if you are getting the login error.

Then you need to do a login, `heroku login` and type in your heroku credentials. This should either give you an error message or say something like "Can't find existing public key.." Reply with what this says.

If you get an error, you can try deleting your `/Users/USERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file and then repeating the above steps.  Update me on the status with error messages from these steps.

Comment: I did set up the heroku gem, then I used heroku add:keys (Which creates a new key if there's none [and it did that]), I also logged on my account with heroku login and there was no error. All these steps work just fine, I only get the Permission Denied when I try to pull my existing repository.